# What is Luther Allison saying on a fragment of the song, "Nobody But You."

Tags: blues

http://youtu.be/GuP36qwe91Q

Here is a link to the song *nobody but you* by Luther Allison.

At 2:00 to 2:08, what is he saying? I can hear that he says:

> sweet little angel say that you *done* me wrong

Is it done? Or got?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that's what he's saying, yes. [One lyrics site](http://www.lyricsmania.com/nobody_but_you_lyrics_luther_allison.html) seems to think that it's "done", while [another one](http://www.songlyrics.com/luther-allison/nobody-but-you-lyrics/) seems to think it's "got".

I'm not hearing "got" at all though. In addition, "you done me wrong" is such [a common blues and rock'n'roll phrase when singing about a woman](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22you%20done%20me%20wrong%22%20blues) that I'd be inclined to conclude that the phrase he's singing is exactly what you wrote:

> Sweet little angel say that you done me wrong